# A problem which I encountered in Eclipse

Tags: 14.04, eclipse, c++, c, eclipse-cdt

I have written a simple code in Eclipse/C Project as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
};

 list Listptr;

int findTheSmallest()
{

}

int main()
{
    printf("Trying");
}
```

However, `list Listptr;` line cannot be read by the Eclipse/C compiler. 
I am using Eclipse Mars and CDT 8.7.0

Eclipse wants me to add struct definition in front of the `list Listptr;` but when I try the program in Visual Studio it works without any problem. What can I do for Eclipse? I want to use how I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't write `struct` there - it won't be a valid C code.

Visual Studio doesn't care much about C, it's using a C++ compiler.

So, to avoid writing `struct`, use the `typedef list { ... } list_t` to define a `list_t` typename:

```
typedef struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} list_t;

list_t Listptr;
```